# Core Audio — How do I get a file's AudioChannelLayout? kAudioFilePropertyChannelLayout not working.

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm trying to get the channel order from 6-channel aac files. What I have now is this:

```
status = AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)inFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputFile);
NSAssert(status == noErr, @"Audio file open error. status:%d", (int)status);

AudioChannelLayout *fileChannelLayout;
UInt32 channelLayoutSize = sizeof(AudioChannelLayout);

fileChannelLayout = (AudioChannelLayout *) calloc(1, channelLayoutSize); 

status = AudioFileGetProperty(inputFile, kAudioFilePropertyChannelLayout, &channelLayoutSize, &fileChannelLayout);
NSAssert(status == noErr, @"Get channel layout error. status:%d", (int)status);
```

But I'm not getting anything into the AudioChannelLayout struct. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way of figuring out what position each channel belongs to (e.g.: L,R,C,SL,SR,LFE)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

```
AudioFileID audioFie; // should already be opened
UInt32 dataSize;
OSStatus result = AudioFileGetPropertyInfo(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyChannelLayout, &dataSize, nullptr);
if(noErr == result) {
    auto channelLayout = (AudioChannelLayout *)malloc(dataSize);
    result = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyChannelLayout, &dataSize, channelLayout);

    if(noErr == result)
        // Handle error
        free(channelLayout);
    }
    else 
        // Handle error
}
```